# Apache local VirtualHost redirecting to other VirtualHost

Tags: wordpress, apache, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up a simple WordPress dev environment using the Sage theme. I'm not too familiar with how VirtualHosts work, but I've just been following the steps I remember from setting one up in the past.

I have created a config file for my project:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName project1.loc
  DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/project1"
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/project1.loc-error_log"
  CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/project1.loc-access_log" common

  <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/project1">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

There are a couple other config files exactly like this located in my vhosts directory.

In hosts:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##

127.0.0.1 project1.loc
127.0.0.1 project2.loc
127.0.0.1 project3.loc
127.0.0.1 project4.loc

127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I've updated the devUrl in the `manifest.json` file of the Sage theme:

```
"config": {
    "devUrl": "http://project1.loc"
  }
```

I have restarted apache using: `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart`

When I run `gulp watch` in the Sage directory, I get this:

```
[16:22:59] Using gulpfile /Library/WebServer/Documents/project1/wp-content/themes/project1/gulpfile.js
[16:22:59] Starting 'watch'...
[16:22:59] Finished 'watch' after 29 ms
[BS] Proxying: http://project1.loc
[BS] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://##.#.#.##:3001
 ----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://##.#.#.##:3001
 ----------------------------------
```

which seems fine. The problem is that this redirects to `project3.loc` for some reason. I can, however, access `project1.loc/wp-admin` or any other url that isn't the root just fine.

Is there a step I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. It was being cached. Clearing the cache fixed the problem. Dumb mistake.